# ignite 2.0: Android back button closing app react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using default ignite 2.0 boilerplate code.
Suppose I open a new screen using `this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen')`

After opening the 'SecondScreen' if I am pressing android hardware back button it is closing app. 'SecondScreen' ui back button at top of screen is working fine.

App navigation code:

```js
const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  SecondScreen: { screen: SecondScreen }
}, {
    // Default config for all screens
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: styles.header
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using Redux integration, which means you'll need to handle the back button yourself as pointed out [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html). Also check out [the reference for Backhandler](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling.html).

What I've done is implement it like this:

```js
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

/* subscribe this to the redux store, should look something like this subscriber(store.dispatch, store.getState); */
export const subscriber = (dispatch, getState) => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    const appShouldExit = true || false; //depending on which screen you're at
    if (appShouldExit) {
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
        
    const backAction = NavigationActions.back();
    dispatch(backAction);
    
    return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my component I added this code and it is working fine now.

```
  import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.props.navigation.goBack);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.props.navigation.goBack);
  }
```